# Nice to have a dark and light theme

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

Was just thinking, if it would be nice if we have a dark theme customization and the current light theme.

Comment: I agree, except for the bit about the light theme.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thank you for pointing out. Will check it out.